# Java MySQL - Unknown Null Pointer Exception in simple MySQL Login Frame

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a simple login screen that connects to a MySQL database.  It connects just fine, but it throws a null pointer exception when it tries to execute. Here are two snippets of my code as well as the stack trace. I bolded the line where the exception is being thrown.

```
package GUI;

import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class LogInFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame
{

    Connection con;
    Statement st;
    ResultSet rs;

    // Login Constructor
    public LogInFrame()
    {
        connect();
        initComponents();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public void connect(){
         try
        {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://instance44668.db.xeround.com:5719/obliquedb?"
                    + "user=NAME2&password=PASS");
        }
        catch (SQLException ex)
        {
            System.err.println("Cannot connect to database server");
            System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
        } 
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                con.close();
            } 
            catch (SQLException ex)
            {
                System.out.println("Better luck next time");
            }
        } 
    }
```

and here is the method that executes the statement

```
private void acceptButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)                                         
    {                                             
        try 
        {

            String user = userTextField.getText().trim();
            char[] password = passwordTextField.getPassword();
            String pass = new String(password);

            String query = "SELECT username,password FROM users WHERE username = '"+user+"'and password = '"+pass+"'";

  EXCEPTION THROWN-**rs = st.executeQuery(query);**

            int count = 0;
            while(rs.next())
            {
                count++;
            }

            if(count == 1) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, 
                        "Login Successful", 
                        "Error Message", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
            else if(count > 1) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, 
                        "Duplicate Records Found!", 
                        "Error Message", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
            else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, 
                        "User Not Found", 
                        "Error Message", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error Retrieving Records" + e);
    }                                        
    }
```

and stack trace

```
Error Retrieving Recordsjava.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at GUI.LogInFrame.acceptButtonActionPerformed(LogInFrame.java:178)
    at GUI.LogInFrame.access$000(LogInFrame.java:7)
    at GUI.LogInFrame$1.actionPerformed(LogInFrame.java:94)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2713)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:707)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:680)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:678)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:677)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Comment: My wild guess is that `st` might not have been initialized..

Comment: tried that route, still nothing.

Comment: It would be much helpful if you put the complete `stacktrace` of exception? and the line number where `exception` is throwing

Comment: stack trace added and highlighted the line in the actionperformed method where the exception was thrown

Comment: I still feel that `st` is `null`. It can be assured by seeing your that method where you have initialized `st`

Comment: This is **not** complete code -- line 94 of GUI.loginFrame is where the exception is thrown and your paste only has 85 lines.

Comment: @VishalK You were right, st was null, connection was closing before it my method could be called.  Moved the st inside the connect and it works fine. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `connect` the connection is immediately closed.

The statement better should be a PreparedStatement (having miscellaneous advantages).

So create the statement in connect too and remove the finally.

Make a `disconnect` called on application exit closing the statement and connection.

The result set `rs` should be close too.

```
       String query = "SELECT username,password "
           + "FROM users "
           + "WHERE BINARY username = ? "
           + "AND BINARY password = ?";
```

For case sensitive comparison, either specify a binary collation for the columns,
or use BINARY.

Passwords can be handled more appropiately, but as we are talking about a desk top
application it's fine.

Comment: Thank you Joop. I moved the code around, and connection stays open now.  Successfully able to connect to DB. Cheers!